# repeated measures threeway linear mixed model

Tags: r, mixed-model, repeated-measures, multiple-comparisons

I'm new to using R, only started in the last 2 weeks so I apologize if I'm missing something very obvious. 
I am analyzing data from a repeated measures experiment with three factors, diversity (2 levels), temperature(2 levels) and par (3 levels), with ecosystem respiration as my variables. 
So far I've been successful in running a mixed model with the code

```
lmermod.e<- lmer(er ~ div:par+div:tem+tem:par + (1 | week), data=mm)
```

I now need to do a pairwise comparison, 
I've tried ...

```
summary(glht(ermod.e,linfct=mcp(div="Tukey")))
```

but get this error message...

```
Error in summary(glht(ermod.e, linfct = mcp(div = "Tukey"))) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function 'summary': Error in mcp2matrix(model, linfct = linfct) : 
  Variable(s) ‘div’ of class ‘integer’ is/are not contained as a factor in ‘model’.
```

I am aware that wouldn't be appropriate to test the interactions I have. I have also tried the aov, with

```
anovaer<-aov(er ~ div:tem + tem:par + par:div + (1 | week), data=mm)
summary(anovaer)
anova(anovaer)
TukeyHSD(anovaer)
```

but I just get this

```
Error in TukeyHSD.aov(anovaer) : no factors in the fitted model
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In replications(paste("~", xx), data = mf) :
  non-factors ignored: div, tem
2: In replications(paste("~", xx), data = mf) :
  non-factors ignored: tem, par
3: In replications(paste("~", xx), data = mf) :
  non-factors ignored: div, par
```

when I try `lsmeans`

```
lsmeans(ermod.i, pairwise~tem*par*div, adjust="tukey")
```

I get...

```
Error in solve.default(L %*% V0 %*% t(L), L) : 
  Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[1,1] =
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: to add temp par div are separated by Asterisk in  the lsmeans code it just hasn't appeared when typed on this forum